# Create button within textbox textbox text as button name or button Id

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want create button in textbox,The button should have button name as textbox value.
The button should be displayed within textbox.

Markup

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="textbox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  TextMode="MultiLine"
        ontextchanged="textbox1_TextChanged">
    </asp:TextBox>
```

Code

```
 protected void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = textbox1.Text;
            btn.Text = textbox1.Text;
            textbox1.Controls.Add(btn);

        }
```

Comment: Please be MUCH more clear. You have tagged this with 3 different tags and not given any details of where you want this

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to assign button name dynamically when textbox value changes,

Call this the below function in  onBlur event of textbox. So When you leave from text box the button name and value can be changed

```
    function callFun(obj) {
        document.getElementById('dynamicButton').name=obj.value;
        document.getElementById('dynamicButton').value=obj.value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="textbox" id="text1" onblur="callFun(this);">
<input type="button" name="name1" id="dynamicButton" value="test"/>
```

Comment: thanks for replay but this is not my requirement